# Converting .GXT coordinates to .KML (Google Earth) coordinates

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have a .gxt file that I need to convert to .kml. This is what .gxt file looks like inside:

```
[FormatInfo]
format_ver=2
[GeoMain]
ntc_id=1
adm=G
sat_name=APSTAR-6D
long_nom=134.00 
n_diag=1
[COHeader]
beam_id=73
emi_rcp=E
polar_disc=C
reason=C
n_bore=1
n_cont=3
[B1]
gain=58.11
p=-178.5540;-15.1780
[C1]
gain=55.00
n_point=99
P1=-173.4080;-9.7320
P2=-172.3240;-9.8840
P3=-170.9100;-10.1780
P4=-169.9580;-10.4330
P5=-169.3460;-10.6300
P6=-168.0800;-11.1070
P7=-167.5420;-11.3460
P8=-166.6900;-11.7740
P9=-165.6300;-12.4390
P10=-165.0370;-12.9480
P11=-164.8610;-13.0990
P12=-164.3020;-13.7570
P13=-163.9820;-14.4110
P14=-163.9460;-14.5930
P15=-163.8240;-15.0620
P16=-163.7690;-15.7110
P17=-163.8530;-16.3580
P18=-164.0560;-16.8580
P19=-164.1040;-17.0000
P20=-164.5450;-17.6360
P21=-164.9380;-17.9960
P22=-165.2620;-18.2620
P23=-166.0550;-18.7560
P24=-166.2420;-18.8760
P25=-167.2000;-19.3930
P26=-167.4090;-19.4820
P27=-168.4140;-19.8620
P28=-169.1310;-20.0620
P29=-169.6590;-20.2070
P30=-170.8960;-20.4840
P31=-171.7640;-20.5990
P32=-172.1510;-20.6540
P33=-173.4000;-20.7530
P34=-174.6280;-20.8050
P35=-175.8380;-20.8090
P36=-177.0400;-20.7480
P37=-178.2100;-20.6680
P38=-179.3520;-20.5640
P39=179.5250;-20.4260
P40=178.4350;-20.2830
P41=177.4280;-20.2560
P42=176.5120;-20.3840
P43=175.6440;-20.5830
P44=175.2560;-20.6810
P45=174.7920;-20.7840
P46=173.9340;-20.9310
P47=173.0470;-20.9680
P48=172.1250;-20.8680
P49=171.1830;-20.6590
P50=170.7140;-20.5070
P51=170.2250;-20.3410
P52=169.2530;-19.9090
P53=169.0760;-19.8100
P54=168.2490;-19.2790
P55=168.0670;-19.1420
P56=167.3380;-18.4880
P57=167.1900;-18.3280
P58=166.7750;-17.8450
P59=166.3710;-17.2110
P60=166.1060;-16.5850
P61=165.9260;-15.9640
P62=165.8270;-15.3480
P63=165.8100;-14.7370
P64=165.9070;-14.1310
P65=166.0320;-13.5280
P66=166.0740;-13.3340
P67=166.1920;-12.9280
P68=166.4880;-12.3320
P69=166.6170;-12.1540
P70=167.0340;-11.7430
P71=167.2640;-11.5020
P72=167.8860;-11.1600
P73=167.9650;-11.1210
P74=168.7230;-11.0350
P75=169.5250;-11.1370
P76=169.7300;-11.1950
P77=170.3580;-11.3380
P78=171.1990;-11.4960
P79=172.0390;-11.5710
P80=172.8780;-11.5710
P81=173.7170;-11.4900
P82=174.5510;-11.3230
P83=174.6640;-11.2980
P84=175.3960;-11.1300
P85=176.2510;-10.9100
P86=176.8730;-10.7400
P87=177.1180;-10.6630
P88=177.9970;-10.3830
P89=178.8060;-10.1740
P90=178.9060;-10.1470
P91=179.8420;-9.9320
P92=-179.1920;-9.7400
P93=-178.4540;-9.6230
P94=-178.1900;-9.5790
P95=-177.1380;-9.5030
P96=-176.0310;-9.5030
P97=-174.8610;-9.5810
P98=-173.6300;-9.7030
P99=-173.4080;-9.7320
[C2]
gain=53.00
n_point=139
P1=-172.8870;-7.2870
P2=-171.7300;-7.4490
P3=-170.3260;-7.7030
P4=-169.0670;-7.9710
P5=-168.8140;-8.0250
P6=-167.1500;-8.4670
P7=-166.5540;-8.6430
P8=-165.2880;-9.0260
P9=-164.3980;-9.3160
P10=-163.1380;-9.7350
P11=-162.3840;-9.9960
P12=-160.5100;-10.6720
P13=-160.4870;-10.6800
P14=-158.7950;-11.3680
P15=-157.1220;-12.0620
P16=-156.5600;-12.3260
P17=-155.5850;-12.7600
P18=-154.1810;-13.4610
P19=-153.0220;-14.1610
P20=-152.0360;-14.8590
P21=-151.1600;-15.5600
P22=-150.6300;-16.1030
P23=-150.4890;-16.2570
P24=-150.5670;-16.9250
P25=-151.0180;-17.5800
P26=-151.2490;-18.0430
P27=-151.3750;-18.2400
P28=-152.1430;-18.8810
P29=-152.9580;-19.3400
P30=-153.2840;-19.5040
P31=-154.6210;-20.1170
P32=-154.9610;-20.2680
P33=-156.1740;-20.7180
P34=-156.9590;-20.9730
P35=-157.9490;-21.3060
P36=-158.8220;-21.5660
P37=-160.0270;-21.8770
P38=-160.6450;-22.0180
P39=-162.4140;-22.3590
P40=-162.7030;-22.4130
P41=-164.0720;-22.6550
P42=-165.6560;-22.9000
P43=-165.8200;-22.9230
P44=-167.1810;-23.0920
P45=-168.6580;-23.2330
P46=-169.9610;-23.3760
P47=-170.0430;-23.3850
P48=-171.3700;-23.5210
P49=-172.6680;-23.6180
P50=-173.9100;-23.7160
P51=-174.7220;-23.7990
P52=-175.0900;-23.8350
P53=-176.2360;-23.9410
P54=-177.3560;-24.0300
P55=-178.4370;-24.1250
P56=-179.5050;-24.1920
P57=-179.8050;-24.2130
P58=179.4580;-24.2610
P59=178.4460;-24.3270
P60=177.4440;-24.3670
P61=176.4400;-24.3580
P62=175.4250;-24.2810
P63=174.4130;-24.1580
P64=173.3990;-23.9760
P65=172.9490;-23.8690
P66=172.3810;-23.7300
P67=171.3620;-23.4170
P68=170.4680;-23.1010
P69=170.3520;-23.0580
P70=169.3380;-22.6160
P71=168.8700;-22.3820
P72=168.3260;-22.0950
P73=167.5870;-21.6840
P74=167.3280;-21.5310
P75=166.4720;-21.0010
P76=166.3440;-20.9130
P77=165.5220;-20.3300
P78=165.3650;-20.2060
P79=164.6790;-19.6690
P80=164.3940;-19.4120
P81=163.9470;-19.0170
P82=163.4240;-18.4840
P83=163.3170;-18.3730
P84=162.8280;-17.7370
P85=162.4550;-17.1090
P86=162.3500;-16.8730
P87=162.1700;-16.4860
P88=161.9560;-15.8690
P89=161.8770;-15.2570
P90=161.9420;-14.6580
P91=161.9430;-14.6520
P92=162.0950;-14.0500
P93=162.2900;-13.4520
P94=162.4110;-13.1870
P95=162.5570;-12.8560
P96=162.8780;-12.2640
P97=162.9600;-12.1230
P98=163.1740;-11.6720
P99=163.4830;-11.0820
P100=163.5170;-11.0290
P101=163.8430;-10.4950
P102=164.1140;-10.1280
P103=164.2640;-9.9090
P104=164.7110;-9.3240
P105=164.7310;-9.3030
P106=165.3050;-8.7430
P107=165.3830;-8.6760
P108=166.0410;-8.1630
P109=166.0560;-8.1530
P110=166.7500;-7.7390
P111=167.1240;-7.5880
P112=167.4690;-7.4660
P113=168.2050;-7.2660
P114=168.9560;-7.1100
P115=169.6930;-7.0310
P116=169.7250;-7.0280
P117=170.5140;-7.0240
P118=170.9040;-7.0460
P119=171.3230;-7.0740
P120=172.1530;-7.1850
P121=173.0050;-7.3470
P122=173.8790;-7.5400
P123=174.7650;-7.6910
P124=174.8200;-7.6940
P125=175.6560;-7.7480
P126=176.2070;-7.7150
P127=176.5500;-7.6980
P128=177.4550;-7.5930
P129=178.3820;-7.4970
P130=179.3300;-7.3890
P131=-179.6930;-7.3030
P132=-178.6920;-7.2010
P133=-178.5990;-7.1950
P134=-177.6550;-7.1350
P135=-176.5770;-7.1060
P136=-175.4570;-7.0970
P137=-174.2820;-7.1510
P138=-173.0440;-7.2650
P139=-172.8870;-7.2870
[C3]
gain=51.00
n_point=136
P1=-145.7470;-24.7860
P2=-151.7070;-24.8890
P3=-154.8920;-24.9700
P4=-155.5340;-24.9950
P5=-158.3500;-25.1100
P6=-160.6980;-25.2210
P7=-161.6060;-25.2520
P8=-162.8050;-25.2930
P9=-164.7130;-25.3500
P10=-166.4500;-25.4140
P11=-168.0700;-25.4700
P12=-169.0530;-25.4950
P13=-169.6010;-25.5120
P14=-171.0140;-25.5880
P15=-172.3470;-25.6770
P16=-173.6270;-25.7590
P17=-174.8570;-25.8390
P18=-174.9380;-25.8450
P19=-176.0290;-25.9370
P20=-177.1540;-26.0460
P21=-178.2540;-26.1390
P22=-179.3360;-26.2130
P23=-179.9910;-26.2550
P24=179.6110;-26.2860
P25=178.5740;-26.3390
P26=177.5380;-26.3530
P27=176.4900;-26.2980
P28=175.4230;-26.1600
P29=174.3560;-25.9680
P30=174.3210;-25.9600
P31=173.2850;-25.7100
P32=172.2190;-25.3970
P33=171.5130;-25.1480
P34=171.1560;-25.0250
P35=170.0980;-24.5920
P36=169.6650;-24.3950
P37=169.0540;-24.1150
P38=168.1460;-23.6680
P39=168.0310;-23.6090
P40=167.0190;-23.0500
P41=166.8600;-22.9610
P42=166.0360;-22.4900
P43=165.6570;-22.2650
P44=165.0760;-21.9110
P45=164.5590;-21.5800
P46=164.1300;-21.2870
P47=163.5920;-20.9080
P48=163.1970;-20.6130
P49=162.7120;-20.2440
P50=162.2790;-19.8870
P51=161.9210;-19.5890
P52=161.3650;-19.0610
P53=161.2460;-18.9430
P54=160.6810;-18.3040
P55=160.4290;-17.9770
P56=160.2050;-17.6720
P57=159.8000;-17.0460
P58=159.4680;-16.4260
P59=159.4310;-16.3300
P60=159.2380;-15.8100
P61=159.0900;-15.2000
P62=158.9910;-14.5930
P63=158.9480;-13.9900
P64=158.9830;-13.3910
P65=158.9840;-13.3820
P66=159.1060;-12.7960
P67=159.2540;-12.2030
P68=159.4380;-11.6380
P69=159.4490;-11.6120
P70=159.7940;-11.0250
P71=160.0060;-10.7080
P72=160.2030;-10.4400
P73=160.5990;-9.9250
P74=160.6560;-9.8570
P75=161.2140;-9.2770
P76=161.2140;-9.2770
P77=161.8360;-8.6970
P78=161.8420;-8.6920
P79=162.4840;-8.1680
P80=162.5450;-8.1200
P81=163.1400;-7.7170
P82=163.3720;-7.5440
P83=163.8000;-7.2300
P84=164.1680;-6.9670
P85=164.4720;-6.7840
P86=165.1580;-6.4060
P87=165.1830;-6.3930
P88=165.8560;-6.0820
P89=166.5450;-5.8210
P90=166.5690;-5.8130
P91=167.2930;-5.5890
P92=168.0310;-5.4100
P93=168.7820;-5.2720
P94=168.8960;-5.2570
P95=169.5470;-5.1730
P96=170.3260;-5.1000
P97=171.1180;-5.0550
P98=171.9270;-5.0400
P99=172.7500;-5.0390
P100=173.5890;-5.0440
P101=174.4440;-5.0460
P102=175.3120;-5.0120
P103=176.1970;-4.9730
P104=177.1020;-4.9350
P105=178.0310;-4.9190
P106=178.9790;-4.8780
P107=179.9500;-4.8170
P108=-179.4440;-4.7780
P109=-179.0530;-4.7530
P110=-178.0160;-4.7740
P111=-177.7360;-4.7960
P112=-176.9390;-4.8510
P113=-175.8160;-4.9920
P114=-174.6450;-5.1590
P115=-173.4190;-5.3650
P116=-172.9780;-5.4560
P117=-172.1260;-5.6170
P118=-170.7550;-5.9160
P119=-169.9910;-6.1080
P120=-169.2890;-6.2700
P121=-167.7080;-6.6700
P122=-167.3660;-6.7650
P123=-165.9740;-7.1430
P124=-164.9770;-7.4270
P125=-164.0370;-7.6940
P126=-162.6790;-8.0980
P127=-161.8050;-8.3530
P128=-160.3440;-8.7780
P129=-159.1170;-9.1290
P130=-157.8970;-9.4720
P131=-155.5020;-10.1370
P132=-155.3430;-10.1780
P133=-152.2590;-10.9110
P134=-148.2830;-11.5970
P135=-147.0950;-11.7220
P136=-145.0340;-11.7970
```

So for each set of points P1 to PN, I make a polygon for each of them in a .kml file.
This is what it looks like when converted to .kml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document id="29">
        <Placemark id="31">
            <name>Polygon 1</name>
            <Polygon id="30">
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing id="32">
                        <coordinates>-173.408,-9.732,0.0 -172.324,-9.884,0.0 -170.91,-10.178,0.0 -169.958,-10.433,0.0 -169.346,-10.63,0.0 -168.08,-11.107,0.0 -167.542,-11.346,0.0 -166.69,-11.774,0.0 -165.63,-12.439,0.0 -165.037,-12.948,0.0 -164.861,-13.099,0.0 -164.302,-13.757,0.0 -163.982,-14.411,0.0 -163.946,-14.593,0.0 -163.824,-15.062,0.0 -163.769,-15.711,0.0 -163.853,-16.358,0.0 -164.056,-16.858,0.0 -164.104,-17.0,0.0 -164.545,-17.636,0.0 -164.938,-17.996,0.0 -165.262,-18.262,0.0 -166.055,-18.756,0.0 -166.242,-18.876,0.0 -167.2,-19.393,0.0 -167.409,-19.482,0.0 -168.414,-19.862,0.0 -169.131,-20.062,0.0 -169.659,-20.207,0.0 -170.896,-20.484,0.0 -171.764,-20.599,0.0 -172.151,-20.654,0.0 -173.4,-20.753,0.0 -174.628,-20.805,0.0 -175.838,-20.809,0.0 -177.04,-20.748,0.0 -178.21,-20.668,0.0 -179.352,-20.564,0.0 179.525,-20.426,0.0 178.435,-20.283,0.0 177.428,-20.256,0.0 176.512,-20.384,0.0 175.644,-20.583,0.0 175.256,-20.681,0.0 174.792,-20.784,0.0 173.934,-20.931,0.0 173.047,-20.968,0.0 172.125,-20.868,0.0 171.183,-20.659,0.0 170.714,-20.507,0.0 170.225,-20.341,0.0 169.253,-19.909,0.0 169.076,-19.81,0.0 168.249,-19.279,0.0 168.067,-19.142,0.0 167.338,-18.488,0.0 167.19,-18.328,0.0 166.775,-17.845,0.0 166.371,-17.211,0.0 166.106,-16.585,0.0 165.926,-15.964,0.0 165.827,-15.348,0.0 165.81,-14.737,0.0 165.907,-14.131,0.0 166.032,-13.528,0.0 166.074,-13.334,0.0 166.192,-12.928,0.0 166.488,-12.332,0.0 166.617,-12.154,0.0 167.034,-11.743,0.0 167.264,-11.502,0.0 167.886,-11.16,0.0 167.965,-11.121,0.0 168.723,-11.035,0.0 169.525,-11.137,0.0 169.73,-11.195,0.0 170.358,-11.338,0.0 171.199,-11.496,0.0 172.039,-11.571,0.0 172.878,-11.571,0.0 173.717,-11.49,0.0 174.551,-11.323,0.0 174.664,-11.298,0.0 175.396,-11.13,0.0 176.251,-10.91,0.0 176.873,-10.74,0.0 177.118,-10.663,0.0 177.997,-10.383,0.0 178.806,-10.174,0.0 178.906,-10.147,0.0 179.842,-9.932,0.0 -179.192,-9.74,0.0 -178.454,-9.623,0.0 -178.19,-9.579,0.0 -177.138,-9.503,0.0 -176.031,-9.503,0.0 -174.861,-9.581,0.0 -173.63,-9.703,0.0 -173.408,-9.732,0.0</coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark id="35">
            <name>Polygon 2</name>
            <Polygon id="34">
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing id="36">
                        <coordinates>-172.887,-7.287,0.0 -171.73,-7.449,0.0 -170.326,-7.703,0.0 -169.067,-7.971,0.0 -168.814,-8.025,0.0 -167.15,-8.467,0.0 -166.554,-8.643,0.0 -165.288,-9.026,0.0 -164.398,-9.316,0.0 -163.138,-9.735,0.0 -162.384,-9.996,0.0 -160.51,-10.672,0.0 -160.487,-10.68,0.0 -158.795,-11.368,0.0 -157.122,-12.062,0.0 -156.56,-12.326,0.0 -155.585,-12.76,0.0 -154.181,-13.461,0.0 -153.022,-14.161,0.0 -152.036,-14.859,0.0 -151.16,-15.56,0.0 -150.63,-16.103,0.0 -150.489,-16.257,0.0 -150.567,-16.925,0.0 -151.018,-17.58,0.0 -151.249,-18.043,0.0 -151.375,-18.24,0.0 -152.143,-18.881,0.0 -152.958,-19.34,0.0 -153.284,-19.504,0.0 -154.621,-20.117,0.0 -154.961,-20.268,0.0 -156.174,-20.718,0.0 -156.959,-20.973,0.0 -157.949,-21.306,0.0 -158.822,-21.566,0.0 -160.027,-21.877,0.0 -160.645,-22.018,0.0 -162.414,-22.359,0.0 -162.703,-22.413,0.0 -164.072,-22.655,0.0 -165.656,-22.9,0.0 -165.82,-22.923,0.0 -167.181,-23.092,0.0 -168.658,-23.233,0.0 -169.961,-23.376,0.0 -170.043,-23.385,0.0 -171.37,-23.521,0.0 -172.668,-23.618,0.0 -173.91,-23.716,0.0 -174.722,-23.799,0.0 -175.09,-23.835,0.0 -176.236,-23.941,0.0 -177.356,-24.03,0.0 -178.437,-24.125,0.0 -179.505,-24.192,0.0 -179.805,-24.213,0.0 179.458,-24.261,0.0 178.446,-24.327,0.0 177.444,-24.367,0.0 176.44,-24.358,0.0 175.425,-24.281,0.0 174.413,-24.158,0.0 173.399,-23.976,0.0 172.949,-23.869,0.0 172.381,-23.73,0.0 171.362,-23.417,0.0 170.468,-23.101,0.0 170.352,-23.058,0.0 169.338,-22.616,0.0 168.87,-22.382,0.0 168.326,-22.095,0.0 167.587,-21.684,0.0 167.328,-21.531,0.0 166.472,-21.001,0.0 166.344,-20.913,0.0 165.522,-20.33,0.0 165.365,-20.206,0.0 164.679,-19.669,0.0 164.394,-19.412,0.0 163.947,-19.017,0.0 163.424,-18.484,0.0 163.317,-18.373,0.0 162.828,-17.737,0.0 162.455,-17.109,0.0 162.35,-16.873,0.0 162.17,-16.486,0.0 161.956,-15.869,0.0 161.877,-15.257,0.0 161.942,-14.658,0.0 161.943,-14.652,0.0 162.095,-14.05,0.0 162.29,-13.452,0.0 162.411,-13.187,0.0 162.557,-12.856,0.0 162.878,-12.264,0.0 162.96,-12.123,0.0 163.174,-11.672,0.0 163.483,-11.082,0.0 163.517,-11.029,0.0 163.843,-10.495,0.0 164.114,-10.128,0.0 164.264,-9.909,0.0 164.711,-9.324,0.0 164.731,-9.303,0.0 165.305,-8.743,0.0 165.383,-8.676,0.0 166.041,-8.163,0.0 166.056,-8.153,0.0 166.75,-7.739,0.0 167.124,-7.588,0.0 167.469,-7.466,0.0 168.205,-7.266,0.0 168.956,-7.11,0.0 169.693,-7.031,0.0 169.725,-7.028,0.0 170.514,-7.024,0.0 170.904,-7.046,0.0 171.323,-7.074,0.0 172.153,-7.185,0.0 173.005,-7.347,0.0 173.879,-7.54,0.0 174.765,-7.691,0.0 174.82,-7.694,0.0 175.656,-7.748,0.0 176.207,-7.715,0.0 176.55,-7.698,0.0 177.455,-7.593,0.0 178.382,-7.497,0.0 179.33,-7.389,0.0 -179.693,-7.303,0.0 -178.692,-7.201,0.0 -178.599,-7.195,0.0 -177.655,-7.135,0.0 -176.577,-7.106,0.0 -175.457,-7.097,0.0 -174.282,-7.151,0.0 -173.044,-7.265,0.0 -172.887,-7.287,0.0</coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark id="39">
            <name>Polygon 3</name>
            <Polygon id="38">
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing id="40">
                        <coordinates>-145.747,-24.786,0.0 -151.707,-24.889,0.0 -154.892,-24.97,0.0 -155.534,-24.995,0.0 -158.35,-25.11,0.0 -160.698,-25.221,0.0 -161.606,-25.252,0.0 -162.805,-25.293,0.0 -164.713,-25.35,0.0 -166.45,-25.414,0.0 -168.07,-25.47,0.0 -169.053,-25.495,0.0 -169.601,-25.512,0.0 -171.014,-25.588,0.0 -172.347,-25.677,0.0 -173.627,-25.759,0.0 -174.857,-25.839,0.0 -174.938,-25.845,0.0 -176.029,-25.937,0.0 -177.154,-26.046,0.0 -178.254,-26.139,0.0 -179.336,-26.213,0.0 -179.991,-26.255,0.0 179.611,-26.286,0.0 178.574,-26.339,0.0 177.538,-26.353,0.0 176.49,-26.298,0.0 175.423,-26.16,0.0 174.356,-25.968,0.0 174.321,-25.96,0.0 173.285,-25.71,0.0 172.219,-25.397,0.0 171.513,-25.148,0.0 171.156,-25.025,0.0 170.098,-24.592,0.0 169.665,-24.395,0.0 169.054,-24.115,0.0 168.146,-23.668,0.0 168.031,-23.609,0.0 167.019,-23.05,0.0 166.86,-22.961,0.0 166.036,-22.49,0.0 165.657,-22.265,0.0 165.076,-21.911,0.0 164.559,-21.58,0.0 164.13,-21.287,0.0 163.592,-20.908,0.0 163.197,-20.613,0.0 162.712,-20.244,0.0 162.279,-19.887,0.0 161.921,-19.589,0.0 161.365,-19.061,0.0 161.246,-18.943,0.0 160.681,-18.304,0.0 160.429,-17.977,0.0 160.205,-17.672,0.0 159.8,-17.046,0.0 159.468,-16.426,0.0 159.431,-16.33,0.0 159.238,-15.81,0.0 159.09,-15.2,0.0 158.991,-14.593,0.0 158.948,-13.99,0.0 158.983,-13.391,0.0 158.984,-13.382,0.0 159.106,-12.796,0.0 159.254,-12.203,0.0 159.438,-11.638,0.0 159.449,-11.612,0.0 159.794,-11.025,0.0 160.006,-10.708,0.0 160.203,-10.44,0.0 160.599,-9.925,0.0 160.656,-9.857,0.0 161.214,-9.277,0.0 161.214,-9.277,0.0 161.836,-8.697,0.0 161.842,-8.692,0.0 162.484,-8.168,0.0 162.545,-8.12,0.0 163.14,-7.717,0.0 163.372,-7.544,0.0 163.8,-7.23,0.0 164.168,-6.967,0.0 164.472,-6.784,0.0 165.158,-6.406,0.0 165.183,-6.393,0.0 165.856,-6.082,0.0 166.545,-5.821,0.0 166.569,-5.813,0.0 167.293,-5.589,0.0 168.031,-5.41,0.0 168.782,-5.272,0.0 168.896,-5.257,0.0 169.547,-5.173,0.0 170.326,-5.1,0.0 171.118,-5.055,0.0 171.927,-5.04,0.0 172.75,-5.039,0.0 173.589,-5.044,0.0 174.444,-5.046,0.0 175.312,-5.012,0.0 176.197,-4.973,0.0 177.102,-4.935,0.0 178.031,-4.919,0.0 178.979,-4.878,0.0 179.95,-4.817,0.0 -179.444,-4.778,0.0 -179.053,-4.753,0.0 -178.016,-4.774,0.0 -177.736,-4.796,0.0 -176.939,-4.851,0.0 -175.816,-4.992,0.0 -174.645,-5.159,0.0 -173.419,-5.365,0.0 -172.978,-5.456,0.0 -172.126,-5.617,0.0 -170.755,-5.916,0.0 -169.991,-6.108,0.0 -169.289,-6.27,0.0 -167.708,-6.67,0.0 -167.366,-6.765,0.0 -165.974,-7.143,0.0 -164.977,-7.427,0.0 -164.037,-7.694,0.0 -162.679,-8.098,0.0 -161.805,-8.353,0.0 -160.344,-8.778,0.0 -159.117,-9.129,0.0 -157.897,-9.472,0.0 -155.502,-10.137,0.0 -155.343,-10.178,0.0 -152.259,-10.911,0.0 -148.283,-11.597,0.0 -147.095,-11.722,0.0 -145.034,-11.797,0.0</coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

And it works, when I import it to google earth it looks as it's expected. But it only works for cases where there is no negative coordinates.
As for the example above, some polygon point goes around the earth I assume because of the negative value.

Question is: How do I convert the coordinates from the .gxt file to the appropriate coordinate for .kml (Google Earth)

Comment: I see your issue with the large curved polygons around Fiji, showing as a longitudinal band around the globe. Not sure this is the issue (doesn't quite look like it), but have you tried reversing the winding direction of the polygons, so the vertices are in the correct anti-clockwise order? Also, looks like some of your polygons aren't "closed"... they should have the first and last vertex (set of coordinates) be exactly the same.

Comment: Hello I think the coordinates were correct after all,  because when I used the LineString instead of Polygon, it displayed the expected results